# Where can I find documentation on the Varien Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, magento-1, documentation

Magento ships with a number Varien javascript libraries (located under `js/varien`) which it uses for clientside features such as form validation.

Where can I find an API guide for this, or high level documentation of what's included and how it's intended to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, but I'm certain, nothing like this exists, at least not publicly available. Varien is the company that originally developed Magento and as far as I know Magento is the only software that uses these internal libraries.

No matches on devdocs.magento.com as well.